# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 

Tags: jquery

I have code like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.plus').click(function(){ 
  var url = "/accounts/profile/update_thing/" + $(this).parent().attr('id') + "/",
  $.getJSON(url, function(data){
var items = []

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});  })  
})
```

And Chrome code spectrator saying that i have Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in line 4. But I don't know why. Does someone knows what is about?

Ps. Is it normal that I haven't text editor on this site?

Comment: I suggest commenting out portions of code until you don't see the SyntaxError anymore; its as simple as process of elimination.

Comment: No, it'is not normal. You can indent your code manually with four spaces at the start of a line. You seem to have managed formatting properly in your previous questions (though please stop writing tags in your titles!)

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = "/accounts/profile/update_thing/" + $(this).parent().attr('id') + "/",
  $.getJSON(url, function(data){
```

...is clearly wrong. Did you mean `;` on the first line?

If you indent your code properly then mistakes will be easier to spot.

Comment: When I remove comma error disappear, but now i just getting "Error in event handler for 'undefined': TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined". Could it be because of I don't have DOM elements specified in my jQuery code?

Comment: @Cris: This is a separate issue. I don't know what line you're getting that error on, but I do notice that you never check the validity of `data`. Perhaps you can abstract out the AJAX request and demonstrate the issue in jsfiddle.